# How to add and remove the class of the select input using Jquery addClass( )?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using Uniform JS plugin for the form inputs. in the below code, i was trying to initialize the uniformjs styles in the dynamically created fields also.

In the below html code, there is a function called ext() which inserts a new row when the add button is clicked. I want the uniformjs style to get applied to those dynamically generated fields too. I tried and tried but its getting worst and its getting collapsed and the select boxes are not at all showing the selected value even after selecting ... :(

### HTML

```
<table style="width:100%;border:1px solid;" id="table1">
  <tr><td>
  <select>
            <option>Through Google</option>
            <option>Through Twitter</option>
            <option>Other&hellip;</option>
            <option>&lt;Hi&gt;</option>
  </select>
</td>
<td><button onClick="ext();">Add</button></td>

</tr>
</table>
```

### JS

```
$(function()
{
    $("input, textarea, select, button").uniform();
});

function ext()
{
    $(function()
    {
        $("input, textarea, select, button").uniform();
    });

    rl = document.getElementById("table1").rows.length;

    var a = document.getElementById("table1").insertRow(rl);
    var b = a.insertCell(0);


    b.innerHTML = '<div style="width:95%;margin-bottom:0px;padding:5px;"><div class="selector" id="uniform-clinic_visit"><span style="-moz-user-select: none;">Monthly</span><select name="clinic_visit[]" id="clinic_visit" onChange=""> <option>-Select-</option><option value="Weekly">Weekly</option>         <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option></select></div></div>';
}
```

Resource -  www.uniformjs.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function ext()
        {

        $("#table1").append('<tr><td><div style="width:95%;margin-bottom:0px;padding:5px;"><div class="selector" id="uniform-clinic_visit"><span style="-moz-user-select: none;">Monthly</span><select name="clinic_visit[]" id="clinic_visit" onChange=""> <option>-Select-</option><option value="Weekly">Weekly</option>         <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option></select></div></div></td></tr>');

        $(":input").uniform();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

instead of `"input, textarea, select, button"` you can just use `":input"` it covers all the input type elements.
please try something like below :

```
$(function(){
    $(":input").uniform();
  });

function ext()
        {
        rl=document.getElementById("table1").rows.length;

        var a=document.getElementById("table1").insertRow(rl);
        var b=a.insertCell(0);


    b.innerHTML='<div style="width:95%;margin-bottom:0px;padding:5px;"><div class="selector" id="uniform-clinic_visit"><span style="-moz-user-select: none;">Monthly</span><select name="clinic_visit[]" id="clinic_visit" onChange=""> <option>-Select-</option><option value="Weekly">Weekly</option>         <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option></select></div></div>';

    $(function(){
        $(":input").uniform();
      });
    }
```

Comment: @dku...nope..its affecting all input fields and even other fields will get affected as the rows keep on increasing...!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how Uniform works, so just a guess: within your `ext()` function, move the following code:

```
$("input, textarea, select, button").uniform();
```

to be the last line of the function. That is, call `.uniform()` *after* you create the new elements. (Obviously I'm assuming here that it is the call to `.uniform()` that applies the styles you are talking about.)

Note also that within your `ext()` function you currently surround the above line with a document ready function and you don't need to do that.